# Сериализация в xml (Уникальность полей)

Tags: c#, .net

Делаю сериализацию. Все получается. Но существует необходимость проверять некоторые   поля на уникальность и на заполненость (не пустые). Это можно как то сделать в xml (апример в схеме)? или мне это проверять именно у объектов до сериализации с помощью условий? Годные статейки или книжки приветствуются.

Comment: Вы же проверяете валидность ваших моделей перед сохранением в БД, почему бы не делать то же самое перед сохранением в файл?

Comment: по поводу книжек: [XML Базовый курс](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1533-7.html). Кирпич в 1,5к страниц, но там есть все необходимое с хорошим объяснением, в том числе некоторые старые техники вроде DTD, от которых все еще есть практическая польза в отдельных случаях.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под `уникальностью полей`?

Comment: подразумеваю как и в БД (если уже в поле есть с таким же значением, то исключение вылетает или ошибка). Проверять то можно перед сохранением, но вроде можно как-то по красивее

Comment: Отсутствие валидации ваших моделей или DTO в коде не будет выглядеть красивее, это будет дыра в вашей безопасности.